# Correct use of MPI_Win in a MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE multithreaded level

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to use an MPI_Win with the MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE multithreaded level, but it seems that there is some type of problem that I don't understand. This is an example of the code I'm trying to execute(It's not the original code, but I'm encountering the same error):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    int local_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int global_sum[ARRAY_SIZE];
    char hostname[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int hostname_len;    
    MPI_Win win;

    // Init global sum
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        global_sum[i] = 0;
    }    

    //MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int provided;
    MPI_Init_thread(nullptr, nullptr, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    if (provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE) {
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 5);
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &hostname_len);
    hostname[hostname_len] = '\0';
    std::cout << hostname << "\n";

    // Init local array
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        local_array[i] = rank * ARRAY_SIZE + i;
    }

    // Create window
    MPI_Win_create(global_sum, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);

    // Lock window
    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, 0, 0, win);

    // Action in window
    MPI_Get_accumulate( local_array, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_INT, global_sum, ARRAY_SIZE,
                       MPI_INT, 0, 0, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, win);    

    // Unlock window
    MPI_Win_unlock(0, win);

    // Synchronize ranks
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Print result
    if (rank == 0) {
        std::cout << "Result is: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            std::cout << global_sum[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    // Free window
    MPI_Win_free(&win);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the code using **MPI_Init** all works fine, but when I use **MPI_Init_thread** I'm getting the follow error:

```
[node01:1190989] *** An error occurred in MPI_Win_create
[node01:1190989] *** reported by process [166199296,2]
[node01:1190989] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[node01:1190989] *** MPI_ERR_WIN: invalid window
[node01:1190989] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[node01:1190989] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[node01:1190990] *** An error occurred in MPI_Win_create
[node01:1190990] *** reported by process [166199296,3]
[node01:1190990] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[node01:1190990] *** MPI_ERR_WIN: invalid window
[node01:1190990] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[node01:1190990] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 2536.0 ON node00 CANCELLED AT 2023-05-29T16:16:03 ***
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
srun: error: node01: tasks 2-3: Exited with exit code 53
srun: error: node00: tasks 0-1: Killed
```

The example is launched in a cluster using the Slurm queue system with OpenMPI 4.1.2:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -N2 -n4 -c16 -p testing -A acc_testing -J mpi_win_testing
#SBATCH -o ./slurm.%j.out # STDOUT
#SBATCH -e ./slurm.%j.err # STDERR

# Run simulation
srun -n 4 mpi_win_test
```

Seems there is some erro when the MPI_Win is created. May be it is not possible use MPI_Win with MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE multithreaded level? is something missing in the code? Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your window but your `Get_accumulate` call gives: `Assertion failed in file src/mpi/datatype/typerep/src/typerep_yaksa_pack.c at line 315: FALSE
memcpy argument memory ranges overlap, dst_=0x16d105650 src_=0x16d105650 len_=20`. If I comment that call out, the whole program runs fine.

Comment: Problem being that you need to accumulate into any array but the one that you used as a window buffer. Note: it's better to let MPI allocate the window memory.

Comment: Don't you have a message related to the `OSC pt2pt` component supporting only `RDMA` capable hardware? For example your code works for me on a single node unless I explicitly force the use of the TCP network that is not RDMA capable.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, this happens when I use more than one node. Executing two ranks on the same node works fine. The message I received is the one attached, which comes from the slurm.ID.err file.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Commenting out the line with MPI_Get_accumulate, I'm still receiving the same message.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Another important piece of information that could have an impact is that the cluster is configured using Docker. In other words, the nodes of the cluster are Docker containers. However, I'm not sure if this can have an effect or not.

Comment: Assuming an Infiniband network is available, docker could "hide" it so only TCP/IP is available for inter node communications and hence the failure. I would try without docker first, and if it works, consider using `singularity/apptainer` that is a much better fit for HPC.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Just completed another test with the same code, this time using the MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED multithreaded level instead of the MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE multithreaded level, and it worked fine. However, the issue is that I specifically require the MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE support for the type of application I'm working on. Do you think the issue could be related to Docker? I'm not sure how to check if the InfiniBand network is available, but we have Unified Communication X (UCX) installed. Just in case, these are the Ethernet controllers we have: NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port.

Comment: you can try `export OMPI_MCA_pml=ucx; export OMPI_MCA_osc=ucx` before invoking `srun` and see how it goes.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ok, it seems that UCX is not available:
No components were able to be opened in the pml framework.
Host:      node00
Framework: pml
[node00:3865833] PML ucx cannot be selected.
I'll try without Docker directly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've decided to use the MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED multithreaded level instead of the MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE multithreaded level, and it works fine. I'm not sure why MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE doesn't work, but at least I am able to run my code.

Thank you.